# Django Python, Form show the csrf token

Tags: python, django, forms, token

I'm trying to make a variable form in django but it seems not 
working properly, I hope you can help me because i show me the token instead of form values.

[image]

**Help me please!**

url.

```
url(r'^test', views.test),
```

views.

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        for key, value in request.POST.items():
            response = '%s %s' % (key, value)

        return HttpResponse(response)




    return render(request, 'datos2.html')
```

datos2.

```
<form action="/test" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name="eee">
<input type="submit">
</form>


<p>ADD VALUE</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "text");
    x.setAttribute("value", "0");
    x.setAttribute("name", "eee");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain values from form you should retrieve them from your request object and return in form of context as a part of your rendered template. Here what your code accomplish currently:

Check method of the request

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

Assign to variable response values from POST dictionary, but next value in dictionary overwrites previous one, so as a result, result is last item from POST dictionary, which is csrf token value

```
for key, value in request.POST.items():
            response = '%s %s' % (key, value)
```

Here you return whatever is in your response variable as a http response. You are not rendering template at this step. You just return content of your variable as a response.

```
return HttpResponse(response)
```

And, consequently, execution flow will never reach this statement:

```
return render(request, 'datos2.html')
```

This is it.

I'm not sure i understand you question properly, but if you use post method it means you want to receive values from form. You can do it like this:

```
if 'name_of_your_html_input_field' in request.POST:
                  result=request.POST.get('name_of_your_html_input_field')
return render(request, "template_name.html", {'data':result})
```

And in your template you should:
Put `{{data}}` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The `csrfmiddlewaretoken` *is* a form value. Each time you set `response` in your loop, it overwrites the previous value. In your case, `csrfmiddlewaretoken` is the final item in `request.POST.items()`, so this is the only result you see.

```
    for key, value in request.POST.items():
        response = '%s %s' % (key, value)
```

Instead, you could build up a string, and return it at the end. Then you'll see all the values in `request.POST`.

```
    response = ''
    for key, value in request.POST.items():
        response += '%s %s<br>' % (key, value)

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Note, this will still show the csrf token, because you are showing the values of all the form fields, and the csrf token is a hidden form field. If you don't want to display the middleware token, you could check the key value and exclude it.

```
    response = ''
    for key, value in request.POST.items():
        if key != 'csrfmiddlwaretoken'
            response += '%s %s\n' % (key, value)

    return HttpResponse(response)
```